# Image loading before loading a page with get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, loading

How to display a gif image during the loading ?

i use get.

```
function getCurrentUrl() {
    $(
        $.get(
            "page1.html", 
            function (data) {
                $("#divReceptLoad").empty().append(data);
            },
           'html'
        )
    );
}
```

than you very much if you can help me :)

Comment: Like this? http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/06/show-loading-image-while-page-is.html

Answer (score 4):

Create a `<img id="loading" src="..." style="display:none;" />` then:

```
function getCurrentUrl() {
    $('#loading').show(); //show it before sending the ajax request
    $.get("page1.html", function (data) { 
        $('#loading').hide(); //hide in the callback
        $("#divReceptLoad").empty().append(data);
    },'html'));
}
```

Feel free to add more styling/positioning to the image and replace the basic `show`/`hide` methods with [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)/[fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)/[`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) or [other effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) if you fancy.

Here's a [loading GIF generator](http://loadinggif.com/) and [another](http://ajaxload.info/) in case you don't want to grab one from Google Images.

And here's a [nice collection](http://webpagebynumbers.com/116-free-loading-gif-animations) of premade ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCurrentUrl() {
     $('#gif').fadeIn() // show the hidden gif
     $.get("page1.html", function(data){
        $('#gif').hide() // hide it
        $("#divReceptLoad").empty().append(data);
     },'html')    
}
```